# Import GATE features to csv

Tags: nlp, gate

I am new to GATE Developer. I want use annotation generated by  GATE pipeline as features to the classifier. How can I save those features into a csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the first example here: https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/groovy-recipes/

The easiest way is to use a groovy scripting PR which goes through all annotations and writes where and what you need. Here is a slightly simplified version of the script in the wiki:

```
new File("./outfile.txt").withWriterAppend{ out ->
  doc.getAnnotations().each {anno ->
      if( anno.getFeatures() )
        anno.getFeatures().each{ fName, fValue ->
          out.writeLine(/"${doc.getName()}","${anno.getType()}","${doc.stringFor(anno)}",${anno.start()},${anno.end()},"${fName}","${fValue}"/)
        }
      else
        out.writeLine(/"${doc.getName()}","${anno.getType()}","${doc.stringFor(anno)}",${anno.start()},${anno.end()},,/)        
    }
}
```

It exports only annotations from the default annotation set in some csv format. outfile.txt will be in your gate_home folder.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this a little bit?